# Inline Math in Display Mode

Tags: math-mode, context

I know how to have inline math typeset as in display mode in LaTeX, i.e summations with the index below the sigma, but I'm trying to learn ConTeXt and cannot figure out how to do it.

Any thoughts? Is there a way to do it in ConTeXt?

Comment: Does this link http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Math#Display_math_mode answer your question?

Comment: I believe that `\displaystyle` and `\limits` work also in ConTeXt. Do you have a non working example?

Comment: @egreg Thanks. `\displaystyle` does work. Maybe I had a typo in my original? I don't know. Anyway thanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two ways should work also in ConTeXt:

```
$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i$
```

Probably the second form is preferable, although I usually advise not to put limits above and below in in-line math formulas.